# Cocoa accessibility API: detect if setting an attribute will/did work correctly

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm inserting text in the frontmost application using the Accessibility API by setting `kAXSelectedTextAttribute` with `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue`. In most modern cocoa application, it works perfectly.

However, it doesn't in some apps and I would like to programmatically know whether the active app (or a given `AXUIElement`) supports it.

I tried using `AXUIElementIsAttributeSettable`, but while some apps correctly return `false` (Terminal.app), many incorrectly return `true` (IntelliJ, Sublime Text, FoldingText…). These latter also incorrectly return `AXError.Success` when setting the attribute.

Is there any other way of knowing whether setting an accessibility attribute will/did work correctly?

Comment: You could set it, get it and compare. `AXUIElementIsAttributeSettable` should work, Accessibility Inspector shows a correct '(W)'.

Comment: I face the same problem with Accessibility Inspector: setting `kAXSelectedTextAttribute` in those apps (even though it shows the 'W') doesn't work. I thought about comparing the value, but that brings more problems: setting the selected text removes the selection. I could get around that via `kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute`, but some apps may not support it correctly either (FoldingText) and it makes the selection flickers. Also, some apps (like code editors) reformat the text as soon as it is inserted, making the comparison more difficult (and thus requiring more flickering and "lag").

Comment: There isn't a solution that works for all apps and some apps (Firefox, Sublime Text) don't support Accessibility.

Comment: I know some apps don't support accessibility. What I would like is to programmatically find out whether they do (without a white/blacklist).